# Какие методы отладки использовать когда не понятно какая CMS или freamwork

Tags: php, cms, отладка

Собственно вопрос в названии , какие подходы и алгоритмы использовать при решении не понятных задач и разборе не понятного кода ?

Comment: А какие вы используете когда понятно какая CMS или Framework? В чем разница?

Comment: смотрю код пытаюсь найти признаки каких то cms или фреймворков, использую онлайн сервисы для определения платформы. Может я не совсем правильно написал, интересно как можно разложить по полкам работу приложения т.е по какому алгоритму начинать работу, исследование. Интересуют мнение и советы опытных прогеров )

Answer (score 1):

С помощью дебагера:

1. Ставим ide(phpstorm,netbeans и д.р.)
2. Устанавливаем php-xdebug
3. `xdebug.remote_enable=on` включаем удалённый debug
4. Открываем ide, и конфигурируем запус дебага через xdebug(выбираем удалёный дебаг и конфигурируем сервер для отладки)
5. Ставим точку остановки в 'точке входа проэкта'
6. И запускаем debug
7. После используем навигацию и по шагово проходим в глубь приложения

Добавление от @Kison Да, еще дополнительно можно включить профилирование в xdebug. Затем открываем любую страницу сайта с $_GET параметром XDEBUG_PROFILE, в результате в зависимости от настроек xdebug в папке x получаем файл в котором есть дерево вызовов всех функций приложения. Можно открыть файл для анализа тем же phpstorm

Comment: Да, еще дополнительно можно включить профилирование в xdebug. Затем открываем любую страницу сайта с $_GET параметром XDEBUG_PROFILE, в результате в зависимости от настроек xdebug в папке x получаем файл в котором есть дерево вызовов всех функций приложения. Можно открыть файл для анализа тем же phpstorm

Comment: @Kison Добавил в ответ. Но для профилирование я использую `xhprof`